# Time taken in shared library was high compared to executable,why?

Tags: c++, opencv, dll

**What i do:**

1.I builded the opencv facedetection code in c++ and run the executable

2.I calculated the **detectmultiscale** time in the facedetection code

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <ctime>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)   
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if ( !cap.isOpened() )  // if not success, exit program
    {
         cout << "Can not open camera or video file" << endl;
         return -1;
    }
    CascadeClassifier c;
    if (!c.load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"))
       {
        printf("Error in loading the xml\n");
        return (-1);
       }
    while(1)
    {
        
    Mat image;     
    cap>>image;
    std::vector<Rect> faces;
    clock_t begin=clock();
    c.detectMultiScale( image, faces , 1.1 , 2, 0 | CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
    clock_t stop=clock();
    double secs = double(stop - begin) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000;
    cout<<"Face Detection time in ms= "<<secs<<endl;
    for( int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
    {
       rectangle(image,faces[i],cv::Scalar(0,0,255),2);  
    }
    imshow("Faces",image);
    if(waitKey(10) >= 0) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

3.The time taken by the detectmultiscale in the above code is about **50 ms**

4.I changed the above code in to shared library and called the shared library from test code

```
 testing test;
 test.facedetection(frame);
```

5.The time taken for the detectmultiscale is around **85 ms**

6.Can anybody tell, why the time time taken in the shared library is high compared to the time taken in the executable?

Comment: Try having your program load the DLL before you start your timer.  You want to factor out the DLL loading time from your measurements.  Compare apples to apples.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews,Thanks for the reply
You mean that ,i need to load the DLL in the c++ test code before calling the DLL

Comment: @Thomas Matthews I loaded the DLL before started the timer. Time taken in DLL is 95 - 101 ms. But executable is 56- 70 ms